# How to perform set operations by Oracle SQL over static DATA sets?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need to perform set operations (`MINUS` ,`INTERSECT`, ..) over ***static DATA sets***

For example:

```
SELECT ('a','b') MINUS ('a') from dual;
```

Expected to return `'b'`

```
SELECT ('a','b') INTERSECT ('c') from dual;
```

Expected to return `'a','b','c'`, but I faced

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of [predefined types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm), like here:

```
select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b'))
minus 
select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('c'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative though may not be a nicer one. See [DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56f78/188)

```
(SELECT 'a' from dual 
union 
select 'b' from dual)
MINUS 
select 'a' from dual;
```